# ContentView as Control with own ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Been struggling with this for a while, i have a control inherited from ContentView that has its own ViewModel to manage a variery of paremeters, from the parent page i need to pass just one Property, however i just cant get it to pass across into the ViewModel, if i sont use a view model i use the below and it works fine

Parent Page

```
 <controls:CountdownTimerControl EndDate="{ Binding BidEndDate}">
```

Control

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EndDateProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EndDate), typeof(DateTime), typeof(CountdownTimerControl), default(DateTime), BindingMode.TwoWay,
       propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => ((CountdownTimerControl)bindable).OnIsShown((DateTime)newVal));

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(EndDateProperty);
        set => SetValue(EndDateProperty, value);
    }
```

However if i change my control to use a view model, then the above p[roperty isnt passed via the BindableProperty

```
<controls:CountdownTimerControl EndDate="{ Binding BidEndDate}">
                                                <controls:CountdownTimerControl.BindingContext>
                                                    <viewModels:CountdownViewModel></viewModels:CountdownViewModel>
                                                </controls:CountdownTimerControl.BindingContext>
                                            </controls:CountdownTimerControl>
```

Then it doesnt pass the property at all

Struggling and would appreciate any help

Cheers
A

Comment: It will be an expected result because when you set the BindingContext of CustomView you need to define the property `BidEndDate` in the ViewModel `CountdownViewModel` instead of the parent page .

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks, but then i guess my question is, how do i set the property BidEndDate on the view model to that of BidEndDate from the parent page, i should note that my control is in a ListView so will be triggered multiple times (hence the use of a control)

Comment: Since you reference it in the listview , you should set the value of BidEndDate in ViewModel of ContentPage

Answer (score 1):

Instead of EndDate = "{Binding BidEndDate}",

write EndDate="{Binding Source={x:Reference dem}, Path=BindingContext.BidEndDate}"

Where 'dem' is the name of the main page.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:Markup="clr-namespace:Demo.Helper.MarkupExtensions"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModels"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Demo.Views.UserControls"
         x:Name="dem"
         x:Class="Demo.Views.Dem">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:DemVM />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <controls:CountdownTimerControl EndDate="{Binding Source={x:Reference dem}, Path=BindingContext.BidEndDate}">
        <controls:CountdownTimerControl.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:CountdownViewModel/>
        </controls:CountdownTimerControl.BindingContext>
    </controls:CountdownTimerControl>

</ContentPage>
```